# How to remove an image from a telegram group

Tags: telegram

I sent an image to a telegram group and I want to delete it. but I already delete it for myself. is there any way to delete it for all other members? I am not admin

Answer (score 0):

You need to check `Delete for all members` when delete message, or you might not able to do this.
[image: del]

BTW, if you mean Supergroup, always delete for all members.